# Error opening excel file after odbc connection using MS Excel Driver

Tags: excel, odbc, driver

The problem is when I open an excel file which is connected as an ODBC data source from my application using Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx,...)

I am able to connect through the following connection string and could browse the values from my application.

```
DRIVER={"Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx,...)"};DSN='';FIRSTROWHASNAMES=1;READONLY=TRUE;DBQ=myexcel.xls
```

But while my application is open with the connection open, and try to open the excel file from windows explorer I get the following error message.

```
<excel.xls> cannot be accessed.  The file may be corrupted, isolated on a server that is not responding or read-only.
```

I searched over the internet but couldnt find the solution.

I am using MS Excel 2013 and in Windows 7 and using VS 2012

Comment: Excel files are not meant to be multi-user, especially in this way. If you close the ODBC session, you should be able to open the file with Excel. You *may* be able to open a readonly ODBC session with that file while Excel has it open, but I think this is not likely, and I would not recommend it.

Comment: Ya.  I was working with previous versions of Office i.e. I hope till 2007.  I could open the excel connect to odbc too.  And also I can change the excel and update real-time.

Comment: I think you need to use a real DBMS for your multi-user data store, with which you can interact through Excel and other ODBC (and/or JDBC, OLE DB, ADO.NET, etc.) compliant tools. My employer makes one you can use, in [Open Source](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSIndex) or [Commercial](https://shop.openlinksw.com/license_generator/virtuoso/) form (see [feature comparison](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/features-comparison-matrix/) to learn whether you need or want the latter, which has some [active special offers](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/offers/)).